# Minimum value of exponential order

Tags: real-analysis

Find the smallest value of $\alpha$ such that $f(t)=6^{t+1}$ is of exponential order $\alpha$.
($f$ is said to be of eponential order $\alpha>0$ if there exists $M>0$ suc that $|f(t)|\leq Me^{\alpha t}$ )

We have $f(t)=6\cdot 6^t=6 \cdot e^{(\ln 6) \cdot t}$, Can $\alpha$ be determined from this inspiration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have $0<\alpha < \ln 6$ then you must have that there exists $M>0$ and $T>0$ such that

$$6^{t+1} = 6 e^{(\ln 6) \cdot t} \leq M e^{\alpha \cdot t}$$

for all $t > T$.

This means $6 e^{t(\ln 6-\alpha)} \leq M $, but this is impossible because $\ln 6-\alpha >0 $ so $6 e^{t(\ln 6-\alpha)}$ becomes larger and larger . If we want to find a counterexample then taking $t = \frac{|\ln M|}{\ln 6-\alpha}+T$  suffices to negate  $ 6 e^{t(\ln 6-\alpha)} \leq M $ for any $M$ and $T$ .

Instead, $\alpha = \ln 6$ follows the definition so it is the minimum value we were looking for.